# emacs pinentry in minibuffer prompt blocks other frames?

Tags: frames, minibuffer

I use Emacs in a terminal to read email using mu4e, mbsync. I have

```
PassCmd "gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.authinfo.gpg | awk '/machine imap.gmail.com login rudolf.sykora@gmail.com/ {print $NF}'"
```

in my `.mbsyncrc`. I use Emacs in its server mode and use `emacsclient -c` to connect to it. Further, `pinentry-emacs` is used to get a prompt for a passphrase whenever the passphrase's lifetime has ended.

The prompt appears in the minibuffer of just one frame and *blocks* all other frames. As the prompt may show on a at-the-time remote computer, I now always have to kill Emacs completely, which however spoils the whole meaning of the setup.

Can I do something to have the prompt for a passphrase appear in all frames and so that I can enter the passphrase from any frame? (and all the frames be responsive?)